# each_with_index duplicated records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

first of all, excuse me if my english is not always very good.

I have a problem with the each_with_index... When I show a project, I display the offers for this project. I have to make appear a banner in third position of offers, so I use each_with_index for that.

The problem is that: if I have sixteen offers on a project, I have sixteen times the entirely list of offers, and I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
- @offers.each_with_index do |offer, index|
  - if !user_signed_in? && (@project.published? || @project.pending_attribution?)

    - if @offers.size >= 3 && index == 3
      = render 'offer_cta'

  - contact_bloc = user_contact_bloc(offer.user, viewer: current_user, display_contact_info: offer.display_contact_info?)
  .card.offer-card.mt-4[offer]{ class: offer_class(offer) }
    .card-header.d-flex.justify-content-between.align-items-center.border-bottom-0
      .offer-date
        %span.text-muted
          Offer filed on
          = l(offer.created_at, format: '%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%M')
        - if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? && !offer.user.suspended_at.nil?
          ... exctera
```

Also, if I try this in my console, I don't have any problem...

Have you ever had this problem?

Don't hesitate to ask me if you need more information.

**EDIT :**

This is the code in my render 'offer_cta', a very basic code:

```
.row
        .col-md-12
          .project-cta.p-5.mb-2.text-center
            %h5
              %strong
                blabla
            %p.text-muted blablabla
            %p.m-0
              = link_to "Send a quote", "", class: "btn btn-primary px-3", data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#modal-sign' }, onclick: "ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'Clic', 'Sign up');", tabindex: -1
```

@offers initialization:

```
@offers = @project.offers_accessible_by(current_ability, current_user)
@offers.mark_as_read_for(current_user)
@offers = @offers.includes(:offer_interactions, user: [:user_profile, :user_subscription, :user_contact])
```

Comment: What is code below render for? and what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: *"if I have sixteen offers on a project, I have sixteen times the entirely list of offers"* -- Are you saying that you have `16*16 == 256` offers displaying on the page? As far as I can tell, that would only happen if `@offers` contains 256 items! (And it would have nothing to do with the use of `each` vs `each_with_index`.

Comment: Are those 16 duplicates are identical? the same id and so on. If so, then it looks like you have some "cycle" before this `each_with_index` block. So you are iterating over `@offers` somewhere before this particular `each_with_index` call. Show more code please.

Comment: Hello Umesh, I edited the post to show the code in my render.

Comment: How is @offers.each_with_index implemented?

Comment: Hi Tom, this is exactly my problem, but if I check in my console, @offers contain only 16 records and not 256...

Comment: Hi fl00r, i thought the same thing but there no loop or something like this... My code is rendered in another file but there not "cycle" inside...

Comment: show how `@offers` are initialized.

Comment: Can you show your controller code? Is this for #index?

Comment: the banner is rendered also 16 times? or only once?

Comment: I edited the post to show the controller. This is not for index (works in index) but for show action. And yes, the banner is rendered also 16 times

Comment: the answer is the same. You are iterating over the `@offers` somewhere else. The problem is not in a code you showed. I suppose you should show entire view.

Comment: Well, I need to sleep... I have a "= render partial: "projects/offers/offer", collection: @offers" so the collection is the "problem"... Thanks for your help, I'm going to find how can I work with each_with_index with this collection

Comment: yes, `collection: @offers` is the reason

Comment: Yes fl00r, you are right. It's a big website with a lot of rendered code and I work on this project since few days, so sometimes it's a bit difficult to know exactly how every functionalities works..